# Lodash: Array without last element, no mutation

Tags: javascript, immutability, lodash

I'm looking for a way to retrieve my array without the last element, and without being mutated.

- `_.remove`  does mutate the array and searches by value not index (even if it was [asked there](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/974))
- `_.without` searches by value, not index

I have `_.filter(array, function(el, i) { return i != array.length -1});` but siouf, not really explicit and it needs array to be stored somewhere.

Thanks

Comment: won't array slice work for you ? arr.slice([begin[, end]]). This will create a shallow copy and also you could use -1 for end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was looking for something like "butlast", but I found `initial`, which does the job:

```
var xs = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var xs2 = _.initial(xs);

console.log(xs, xs2);  // [1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

[`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) might help you.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var newArr = array.slice(0, -1);

console.log(array); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(newArr); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Of course you are also able to do it with `lodash`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
_.take(arr, arr.length-1)
```

Comment: Good catch. Though `_.initial` fits my need even better.